# Unable to upload select entry from csv to database MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, file-upload, mern

I am trying to filter data that is going to be uploaded to my database by 1st copying all the data in the selected csv into an array. this array is then inserted into the database through `isertMany()`.

```
`Stds.find({}, (err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json({ items: items });
        }
    });
});


app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    csv()
    .fromFile(req.file.path)
    .then((jsonObj)=>{
        
        var csv = [];
        
        for(var i = 0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
            var obj={};
            obj.enNo=jsonObj[i]['EnNo'];
            obj.name=jsonObj[i]['Name'];
            obj.department=jsonObj[i]['Department'];
            obj.course=jsonObj[i]['Course'];
            obj.batch=jsonObj[i]['Batch'];
            obj.sec=jsonObj[i]['Sec'];
            csv.push(obj)
        }
        //Stds = Model with fields (enNo, name, department, course,                    batch & sec)
        Stds.insertMany(csv).then(function(){
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "Successfully Uploaded!"
            });
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "failure",
                error
            });
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "failure",
            error
        });
    })
});`
```

This works fine but I want to make it so it doesnt accept repeated values.

I tried to copy the array "csv's" acceptable/unique data into a new array called final and then insert it into the database.

```
`let final = []
for(let i = 0; i < csv.length; i++){
            
            if(Stds.findOne({enNo:csv[i].enNo})){
                console.log("Already registered")
            }
            else{
                final.push(csv)
                
            }
            console.log(final)
        }
console.log(final)
```

Final code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Stds.find({}, (err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json({ items: items });
        }
    });
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    csv()
    .fromFile(req.file.path)
    .then((jsonObj)=>{
        
        var csv = [];
        
        for(var i = 0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
            var obj={};
            obj.enNo=jsonObj[i]['EnNo'];
            obj.name=jsonObj[i]['Name'];
            obj.department=jsonObj[i]['Department'];
            obj.course=jsonObj[i]['Course'];
            obj.batch=jsonObj[i]['Batch'];
            obj.sec=jsonObj[i]['Sec'];
            csv.push(obj)
        }
        // console.log(csv)
        let final = []
        for(let i = 0; i < csv.length; i++){
            
            if(Stds.findOne({enNo:csv[i].enNo})){
                console.log("Already registered")
            }
            else{
                final.push(csv)
                
            }
            
        }
        console.log(final)
        //Stds.insertMany(csv).then(function(){
 //           res.status(200).send({
  //              message: "Successfully //Uploaded!"
  //          });
 //       }).catch(function(error){
  //          res.status(500).send({
//                message: "failure",
  //              error
   //         });
 //       });
 //   }).catch((error) => {
//        res.status(500).send({
   //         message: "failure",
   //         error
  //      });
//    })
});`
```

In the above written final code I have commented out the actual uploading part of it as I know it works and I just want to see if the correct data is being copied to the "final" Array, which I could then later pass to the uncommented upload bit.
I wanted it to select entrys with unique "enNos" but what it does is that it only stores the array's last element and when i `console.log(final)` at the end it returns empty array[image]
There are 6 entrys collected from the csv, I want there to 4 when its showing ll six meaning its not following the findOne condition.